# Sorting two lists simultaneously in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists, a and b, and I want to sort them simultaneously (by a), but if two positions in list a are equal, then the sort looks up b. Is there a fast way of doing this, without creating extra temporary lists?

This does the trick:

```
a = [1,2,1,3]
b = [5,0,0,1]
z = sorted(zip(a,b))
a, b = zip(*z)
```

sorted() creates an extra list, is there a way to avoid this if I want fully optimized code?
(I repeat this sorts a lot)

Comment: since the only link between both lists is the index of the element, your method seems appropriate. I don't see how you can compute a key function that, given the value of one of the elements of `a` looks up the relevant element of `b` without zipping both lists together...

Comment: Notice, your code doesn't simply sort your data; `a` and `b` start off as lists in your code and end off as tuples...

Comment: @DanielHao I get the sense from the question they are hoping to sort both lists in-place for efficiency. But I admit, I'm reading between the lines a bit.

Comment: *"I repeat this sorts a lot"* - That's no reason for wanting to avoid the extra list. What's the real reason?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre We *could* trust that `list.sort` applies the key function to the elements in order.

Comment: *"if two positions in list a are equal, then the sort looks up b"* - Is that desired or undesired?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you write your own 'in-place' sorting logic, `sorted()`will be creating a temporary list in one way or another.

To avoid using list b's values in the comparison process, you could sort indexes based on the values of list a and then reorder each list by mapping the sorted indexes to the original list elements:

```
a = [1,2,1,3,2]
b = [5,7,0,1,0]
order = sorted(range(len(a)),key=a.__getitem__)
a[:] = map(a.__getitem__,order)
b[:] = map(b.__getitem__,order)

print(a) # [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
print(b) # [5, 0, 7, 0, 1]
```

If your objective is only to avoid using values of  list b in the sort order, you can provide sorted() with a key function that only uses the first item of the zip tuple:

```
a,b = zip(*sorted(zip(a,b),key=lambda ab:ab[0]))

print(a) # [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
print(b) # [5, 0, 7, 0, 1]
```

Writing your own "in-place" sort will avoid allocation of any extra memory but it will run much slower than the built-in sort (even with the extra memory allocations):

```
# in-place two-list sorting (bubble sort)

for n in range(1,len(a)):
    swapped = False
    for i in range(len(a)-n):
        if a[i]>a[i+1]:
            a[i],a[i+1] = a[i+1],a[i]
            b[i],b[i+1] = b[i+1],b[i]
            swapped = True
    if not swapped:
        break

print(a) # [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
print(b) # [5, 0, 7, 0, 1]
```

Note: There is a sneaky way to perform this sorting "in-place" with the built-in sort (using an iterator as key) but you would end up sorting twice which is likely to be slower than list copying and temporary allocations:

```
a = [1,2,1,3,2]
b = [5,7,0,1,0]

ia = iter(a)
b.sort(key=lambda _:next(ia))
a.sort()

print(a) # [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
print(b) # [5, 0, 7, 0, 1]
```

Comment: I'm curious about what the OP means by "but if two positions in list an are equal, then the sort looks up b". To me this suggests the sorted versions of b should be `[0, 5, 0, 7, 1]`, which is what the OP's code gives with this input.

Comment: I took that to mean that, for duplicate values of `a`, the OP's code would use values of  `b` to determine the order.  This would either prevent the resulting `b` order from being 'stable'  or crash if the OP's actual items in `b` are not comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Numpy?  Even with conversion from `list` to `np.array` and back, it is between 3x and 6x faster on 1-million elements lists in my tests:

```py
import numpy as np

def sort_np(a, b):
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    ix = np.lexsort((b, a))
    return a[ix].tolist(), b[ix].tolist()
```

Comparison:

```py
def sort_py(a, b, as_tuples=True):
    # the OP's method, with result optionally as lists
    a, b = zip(*sorted(zip(a, b)))
    if not as_tuples:
        a, b = list(a), list(b)
    return a, b

def gen(n):
    a = np.random.randint(0, 10000, n).tolist()
    b = np.random.randint(0, 10000, n).tolist()
    return a, b

n = 1_000_000
np.random.seed(0)  # reproducible results
a, b = gen(n)

>>> sort_np(a, b) == sort_py(a, b, as_tuples=False)
True

t_np = %timeit -o sort_np(a, b)
# 398 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

t_py = %timeit -o sort_py(a, b)
# 2.21 s ± 23.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> t_py.best / t_np.best
5.476
```